# best_in_place datepicker format

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, datepicker, date-format, best-in-place

In rails project I'm using `best_in_place` datepicker and have some trouble with date format.

The html generated by `best_in_place`:

```
<span class="best_in_place pull-right" id="best_in_place_task_5_deadline" 
 data-url="/projects/4/tasks/5" data-object="task" data-attribute="deadline" 
 data-type="date" data-original-content="2012-08-16">16 Aug</span>
```

As you can see from `data-original-content` the date format is `yy-mm-dd`, but when I choose the date I've got something like this `09/03/1916`

I've tried to set the date format in `application.js`:

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
```

But it didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It wasn't obvious for me, I had to look inside the code source

```
jQuery(function($){
  $.extend($.fn.datepicker.defaults, { format: 'dd-mm-yy' });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Update (taken from [docs](https://api.jqueryui.com/1.10/datepicker/))

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
});
```